# Way to have inutition about the shape of a curve?

Tags: graphing-functions

Past the usual memorized curves like $y=\sin(x), y=|x|, y=1/x, y=\ln(x), \ldots,$ is there a way to have an intuition about the shape of a curve from looking at an arbitrary function/term?  (that is, other than for transformations of the usual memorized functions and asymptotes that result from prevention of division by zero)

I can’t think of any good examples right now, but a few times in classes the teachers have commented something like “you can see that this function’s/term’s/expression’s  curve will be … (he/she draws on board)…” despite the fact that the function/term/expression is a conglomeration of the basic ones we have memorized the curves for.

Comment: Try to think about long-term behavior, roots, and at least one point with nonzero output: often the $y$-intercept. As en example: $y=(x-1)^2e^{-x}$. In the long term, the exponential outweighs the quadratic. So as $x\to\infty$, this curve's $y$-values approach $0$. And as $x\to-\infty$, this curve's $y$-values approach $\infty$. The only roots are at $x=1$, and locally the function is $\approx c(x-1)^2$ there, so it's graph resembles a parabola near $x=1$ touching the $x$-axis. The $y$-intercept (and in fact every output) is positive. This is all enough information to sketch the curve roughly.

Comment: You talk about curves, and this leads me to interpret you want to deal with maps $\alpha : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n=2$ or $n=3$, but in your question it seems you only want to deal with graphs of functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. So, which of them you want to deal with? General curves in $2$ or $3$ space or graphs of one variable functions?

Answer (score 1):

The way I try to imagine curves is try to identify zeros of the function. And then try to see how the slope is changing by finding its first derivative. And if I want more accurate information I ll try to look for other properties like second derivative to see how the curvature of the graph looks like....

But these kind of things will be learnt only on practice...